# Am having multiple issues with Android 4.4.2 tablet

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android, google, swiftkey

This is a fairly new tablet.   First, I couldn't  get  page reload to stop coming up while using Chrome and stock (google) keyboard.   The manufacturer,  Prestige,  advised me to use the stock browser because Google was having issues with its products working together.  I did,  but then the keyboard would not come up consistently,  especially in email or Web forms where multiple entries were required.   I was advised by the manufacturer to go to SwiftKey keyboard,  and all was basically working well,  until I started having some of the same problems.    I changed to Opera browser,  and am still having same problems.   I have been to the support and knowledge base sites for all problems,  but can't  find answers that apply  or even address some problems,  and I've  been looking through here for a couple of hours now.   At one point,  I did a hard factory reset,  and have cleared data multiple times on Chrome,  Google,  SwiftKey,  and stock browser.   Nothing works for long, if at all.   Thank you for any help.

Comment: I wonder you haven't tried Mozilla's Firefox yet? I'm very happy with Chrome and have uninstalled Firefox tho. And then try `Hacker's Keyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an issue with the dictionary. It probably has a lot of words in it and is taking time to load before the keyboard is displayed. Clear the dictionary or back it up if possible.